# How to send a mail using MAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, email, mapi

I want to send an e-mail using the mail client on the user's Windows computer. As far as I can tell from the net, MAPI is the way to go. However, after reading through the MSDN documentation, I find out that MAPI is quite vast, with no source code examples. And I have no need for 99% of the features, I just want to send an e-mail. How do I do this?

I have found examples here on SO and on the web, but they seem to rely on something called Simple MAPI, which Microsoft has apparently listed as obsolete: "The use of Simple MAPI is discouraged. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows". So I don't want to use those functions.

I found a very good example [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads162/sourcecode/comm/windows_mobile/737963/SendMail/SendMail.cpp__.htm), but unfortunately it is for Windows CE and isn't fully compatible with the Win32 API. I managed to implement the code from that link until it got to where it attempts to open the drafts folder, the parameters to GetProps aren't compatible. Does anyone know where I can find a similar code example for PC? C++ prefered.

Comment: Full MAPI is only present on a Windows machine if you have Outlook or another MAPI client installed.  Windows only comes with simple MAPI.  If you know you've got Outlook installed, why not use Outlook's APIs to send the email?

Comment: The idea is to use whatever MAPI client they have, I'd rather not force people to use a particular e-mail client. But out of curiousity, what exactly are Outlook APIs? Is it VBA or something else?

Comment: If you don't want to force the person to use a particular e-mail client, you're probably stuck with simple mapi.  It won't work if they use web-mail, but most email clients support simple MAPI.  Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg608200.aspx for info on outlook's apis.

Comment: Regarding automating Outlook, this is a pain in terms of testing for supporting older versions. It's fine if you can target one version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by my own, with the help from various internet sources.

[Official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842378.aspx)

[MAPIEx: Extended MAPI Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx)

Once the code is properly tested & documented, I will try to post it here for future reference.

Comment: @DougN Yes I have it up and running in production code now. Unfortunately it is now corporate property so I can't share it as whole. Also, it is customized for the specific application so I'm not sure what value it would hold to others. I am however happy to help out with snippets and hints if anyone else struggles with this. I'm just a rookie at this still though, since I'm normally working with embedded systems, far far from MAPI :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Sending Email using MAPI - A COM DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/email.aspx)

[Edit]

I've used MAPI once and I'll post the code. I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for. This sends a message with optionally attached files ( but no body ).

Header:

```
#pragma once

class MailSender  
{
public:
    MailSender();
    ~MailSender();

    void AddFile(LPCTSTR path, LPCTSTR name = NULL);
    bool Send(HWND hWndParent, LPCTSTR szSubject = NULL);

private:
    struct attachment { tstring path, name; };
    vector<attachment> m_Files;
    HMODULE m_hLib;
};
```

Cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MySendMail.h"
#include <mapi.h>

MailSender::MailSender()
{
    m_hLib = LoadLibrary(_T("MAPI32.DLL"));
}

MailSender::~MailSender()
{
    FreeLibrary(m_hLib);
}

void MailSender::AddFile( LPCTSTR file, LPCTSTR name )
{
    attachment a;
    a.path = file;
    if (!name)
        a.name = PathFindFileName(file);
    else
        a.name = name;
    m_Files.push_back(a);
}

bool MailSender::Send(HWND hWndParent, LPCTSTR szSubject)
{
    if (!m_hLib)
        return false;

    LPMAPISENDMAIL SendMail;
    SendMail = (LPMAPISENDMAIL) GetProcAddress(m_hLib, _T("MAPISendMail"));

    if (!SendMail)
        return false;

    vector<MapiFileDesc> filedesc;
    for (std::vector<attachment>::const_iterator ii = m_Files.begin(); ii!=m_Files.end(); ii++)
    {
        MapiFileDesc fileDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&fileDesc, sizeof(fileDesc));
        fileDesc.nPosition = (ULONG)-1;
        fileDesc.lpszPathName = (LPTSTR) ii->path.c_str();
        fileDesc.lpszFileName = (LPTSTR) ii->name.c_str();
        filedesc.push_back(fileDesc);
    }

    tstring subject;
    if (szSubject)
        subject = szSubject;
    else
    {
        for (std::vector<attachment>::const_iterator ii = m_Files.begin(); ii!=m_Files.end(); ii++)
        {
            subject += ii->name.c_str();
            if (ii+1 != m_Files.end())
                subject += ", ";
        }
    }

    MapiMessage message;
    ZeroMemory(&message, sizeof(message));
    message.lpszSubject = (LPTSTR) subject.c_str();
    message.nFileCount = filedesc.size();
    message.lpFiles = &filedesc[0];

    int nError = SendMail(0, (ULONG)hWndParent, &message, MAPI_LOGON_UI|MAPI_DIALOG, 0);

    if (nError != SUCCESS_SUCCESS && nError != MAPI_USER_ABORT && nError != MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have found that link myself a couple of times. Links like that one is why I wrote that simple MAPI can't be used.

Comment: What's the difference between simple MAPI and full MAPI?

Comment: I'm a beginner at this, but as far as I can tell, [Simple MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296734%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is simple, [extended MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842378.aspx) is enormous. Unfortunately, your code is using Simple MAPI so it may be obsolete.

Comment: That's not the point. I'm writing a program that will have to stick around for 10+ years.

Comment: Btw I read somewhere that Simple MAPI doesn't support HTML, so it is probably out of the question anyhow. I'd rather not give the user the impression that the e-mail was sent in the 80s but arrived just now :)

Comment: What is `tstring`?

Comment: It should be a typedef of std::string or std::wstring, depending on whether it's a unicode or ASCII project (similar to how LPCTSTR works).